# Why kendo mvc grid numeric integer column(numeric text box) is becoming zero , when I give decimal values to it

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendonumerictextbox

I am having **kendo mvc grid** and one of its column is **numeric text box** and it is of type integer , but when I try to give decimal values to numeric text box ,**it is becoming zero , but it should get rounded to nearest integer or should not accept decimal values.**

How can i do that , kindly anyone help me

**CODE:**

columns.Bound(c => c.Quantity).Title("Quantity").Width(100);

public int Quantity { get; set; }

Comment: *"give decimal values to it"* what do you mean ? You are typing the value or setting it programatically ?

Comment: typing the value

Comment: Telerik's demo page here https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline has an mvc bound grid with editable integer values. For example 'Units in stock' (it's actually a short rather than an int but that makes no real difference) which works in the way you want. How does yours differ from this?